# Rellenar DataGrid con DataTable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datatable, datagrid

La situación actual es que tengo esto

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            datagridajuste();
```

El problema es que al rellenar mi "datagrid" (no datagridview) así se me generan tablas vacías al principio y al final. 
Entonces lo que estaba buscando era meter las columnas con el datagrid.Columns.add() pero nunca consigo que funcione con el dt.

Ademas me gustaría saber si alguien sabe como puedo hacer para que una vez lleno el datagrid y con un tamaño establecido desde el principio hacer que el contenido del mismo se ajuste al tamaño del datagrid (he probado con el

```
dataGrid.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMo‌​de.Fill)
```

pero directamente no me reconoce las funciones).

He buscado información sobre datagrid pero todo lo que encuentro esta demasiado anticuado o no especifica las funciones que tienes que importar y no lo puedo usar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aqui te dejo un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo, lo acabo de probar.

Evento load del formulario

```
       private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
            var dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Nombre");
            dt.Columns.Add("Edad");
            dt.Columns.Add("Cedula de la persona");

            dt.Rows.Add("Nombre 1",12,"239847893-4565464");
            dt.Rows.Add("Nombre 2", 16, "23se59847893-4565464");


            dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = 
            DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

       }
```

Lo primero que hice fue crear una tabla de ejemplo, y cree la estructura con el metodo columns.add del data table, luego le agregue varios registros con el metodo rows.add del data table,para llenar el data grid use la propiedad data source del datagrid y para ajustar la columna use la propiedad AutoSizeColumnsMode del data grid y le asigne el enumerable DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode con el valor fill.

La columna cédula de la persona se ajustó automáticamente, y la cree con un tamaño grande para la prueba

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias !!! Voy a probar , por cierto sabrías si se puede quitar esa parte de la izquierda donde sale la flecha ??  Que creo que se usa para seleccionar toda la fila y eso

Comment: Por nada, claro tienes que agregar esta linea  dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;

Comment: Estaba intentando probarlo pero me salta que los métodos no existen para la clase datagrid . Tienes que llamar alguna referencia en especial ?

Comment: Pero en el datagrid no use métodos fueron propiedades (datasource y AutoSizeColumnsMode). Estoy viendo que usas un datagrid y no un datagridview, o es un datagridview que estas usando?

Comment: un datagrid no conocía el datagridview

Comment: El datagrid fue remplazado por el datagridview mira esto https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/differences-between-the-windows-forms-datagridview-and-datagrid-controls

Comment: si eso estaba viendo, lo estoy cambiando, pero una pregunta yo los generaba todos desde el Mainwindows.xaml pero cuando me pongo y llamo al windows form no me sale la opcion y al generarlo yo con forms:DataGridView no me deja poner los campos bien, como puedo hacer para actualizar eso ? o estaba intentando ponerlo yo todos los campos en el Mainwindows.xaml.cs pero los margenes siempre me falla

Comment: Cuando dices que lo generabas todos a que te refieres?

Comment: que el problema es que no conocía bien lo de visual studio y creo que he creado mal algo del proyecto, he generado un WPF y la opción del datagridview esta bloqueada. No se la verdad, hay alguna forma de usar datagridview en WPF o como puedo hacer para pasar el proyecto a un tipo compatible ?

Comment: Ya veo, es que al parecer en wpf no permiten datagridview por defecto solo datagrid, vi varios post donde explican cómo implementar un datagridview pero eso es como forzando el diseño del los formulario wpf. puedes investigar que control te conviene, no tengo mucha experiencia con wpf.

Answer (score 0):

Por si alguien tiene el mismo problema y necesita hacerlo con un datagrid se soluciona así :

```
       //cargo el datagrid 
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

Ahora modifico el datagrid:

```
      double ncolumnas = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Columns.Count);
      double tamlargo = this.dataGrid1.ActualWidth;
    //ajusta el largo de cada columna 
        dataGrid1.ColumnWidth = tamlargo / ncolumnas;
    //quitar scroll 
        dataGrid1.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility= 0;
        dataGrid1.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = 0;
    //quita la que aparece con las flechas ojo no cambiar el header
        dataGrid1.RowHeaderWidth = 0;
```